# Active Admin password format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How can I change the password format in active admin?
I am creating users from the interface and I don't want to use camelcases and numbers for the password format.

Can I do this from inside the config/initializers/active_admin.rb?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it through devise security extension gem :)

https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension